# running " bundle install " command is failure

Tags: ruby, bundle, thor

all,

I use the below command after creating some files in a specific directory. It gets me a error message.

The command

```
desc "new project_name", "new a project with a name"
def new(project_name = 'my_project')
    directory 'doc', project_name
    path =  Dir.pwd + '/' + project_name
    system("cd #{path}")
    run('bundle install')

    #But this command is working that makes me so confusing
    #run("cd #{path} && bundle install")

    #puts "Initializing complete"
end
```

The error

```
create  aaaaaaa/views/index.slim
create  aaaaaaa/views/layout.slim
run  bundle install from "."
Could not locate Gemfile
```

I see the rails that runs this commend `bundle install` directly when it initializes a new project, how the rails can do that? how do i make this command working.

Comment: Is the system command running the "cd /path_to_directory" from a different location? Perhaps starting at / Maybe you should try doing a cd to an absolute directory and checking if that works.

Comment: I have edited my question for fixing. I sure that directory path by `cd` is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-system) creates a subprocess and then exits. The subprocess changed directory and then finished, but your script still thinks it's in whatever working directory the process thinks it's in.

If you want to change the working directory of the process running the script, use [`Dir.chdir()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Dir.html#method-c-chdir).

Comment: Good, adding the command `Dir.chdir(path)` before the `system("cd #{path}")` that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Rails actually uses a little hack that "prints" the bundle install command to the shell and runs it. Notice the back ticks in the output.

```
print `"#{Gem.ruby}" -rubygems "#{Gem.bin_path('bundler', 'bundle')}" #{command}`
```

I also think that the system command doesn't necessarily alter the processes' current working directory (in terms of Thor's run command).